Simplest way to find peak capacitor voltage in this circuit?
I'm curious about how the circuit diagrammed below can most easily be analyzed without the use of a circuit simulator -- the old fashioned way, by hand.

All I'm interested in calculating is the steady-state peak capacitor voltage (getting an actual time-function of the output voltage would also be nice, but is not necessary). Less important to me, but still of some interest, would be the durations of the diode-on and diode-off periods.
So, how would engineers of the pre-simulator era have done this? Note that the diode is ideal, so I'm perfectly willing to just treat it as a switch that opens and closes; even so, I haven't been able to find any particularly simple and easy way to do this. It seems like there's a bit of a catch-22, since the diode state is dependent upon the relationship between cap voltage and source voltage, which is what I'm trying to find in the first place! The problem becomes completely trivial if the source resistor is removed, or if the source is DC, or if the capacitor is removed, of course. But somehow, having all three elements present simultaneously seems to totally wipe out the toolbox of simple approaches to this problem... am I missing something?
What's even more surprising is that, after consulting all of my circuits and electronics textbooks (and I've got quite a few), I haven't been able to find a single one which seems to treat any circuit equivalent to this. Again, if any element is changed (source resistor removed, DC source instead of AC, or no cap), then it's trivial to find coverage of the circuit in basic textbooks, but I haven't found a single book that treats a circuit with all of these elements present. So, a secondary question I have is: what sort of book would I need to get if I wanted to learn more about how to analyze a circuit like this? Any recommendations would be appreciated.

You can eliminate D1 from the analysis provided you apply a piece-wise solution - Half the waveform you have a positive half sine charging the cap through a 10 ohm resistor (and 1k load). The second half you have only have an RC decay. This will simplify the analysis to two simpler problems. The analysis becomes trivial if you consider the time constant of R_SRC*C1 << 120Hz applied voltage. In other words, steady-state is reached after one cycle.

@MOSFET that is far from the truth if you think about it carefully. The diode only conducts when the AC voltage is close to its peak and, stops conducting soon after the peak has occurred.

Well, for such a small load resistance you can assumed that Vout_MaxDC = V1_rms *1.41 - 0.7V

It's fun to see you guys basically recapitulating my own false-start thought processes on this, here in the comments :)
To be clear, I don't care so much about the specific resistance values, and would ideally like to be able to work this out for any R_SRC and R_LOAD.

@ecksemmess How's your non-linear math skills? Are you familiar with the product-log function, for example? It can be solved that way. (I've done it many times before.) It's just a little bit of algebra to get there.

The text books won't provide such a thing, because in reality there is no ideal D1 and Rload much bigger than Rsrc doesn't make sense. There are rules of thumb in text books: Rsrc = 0, D1 is real, C1 designed 1mF per 1 A f = 50 Hz, V1 is a transformator --> gives ... Vpp ripple etc. And a pragramatic approach is to write a little calculation software program for approximation - with that any diagrams of real diodes could be calculated too. E. g. starting with input as UC1min - between 0... UV1p - UD1. Perhaps using finite elements approach for simplicity.

With your factor 100 between the Rsrc & the Rload --> lets say manual approximation = 10.7 V UD1 = 0.7 V, UC1 guess 1: 9V --> 9mA Rload --> 9mA / 120 Hz =  0.075 mC charge consumed each T --> UC1 rises 0.075mC / 1mF = 75 mV ... so the positive pulse charges C1 even after 90° until ist U sinks to 9.075 + 0.7V = 180° - asin(9.775/10.7) = alpha, Uaverage over Rsrc while charging is above 50% from 9 + 0.7 ... to 10.7 V --> URsrcAverage = (10.7 - 9.775) / 2 = ca. 0.5 V, IRsrc = 0.5/10 = 50 mA, so 75uC / 50 mA = 1.5ms --> beta is 1.5 ms before alpha, if Up(beta) is 9.7V = ok, smaller -> UC1 smaller

This work has be done by Schade ... some years ago. https://linearaudio.net/otto-schade-method-practical-design-method-rectifier-circuits https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwTS40IaQa16TUN0TlFxZGE2c0E/edit?resourcekey=0-LwbbH_C9y0a4O8DGYmum8A

@periblepsis Heh, I was afraid that might be where this would end up :) I'm fairly clueless in that area, but it seems worth learning about if it's the "proper" way to work out answers to problems of this type. If you could post a formal answer to my question here with some pointers on how to apply those methods to this particular type of example, I'd be very grateful!

The one in the photo is an adaptation to the problem posed, of a work of mine done years ago, certainly it does not completely answer the question but it is worth taking a look (if you are interested I have the same study done for the double half-wave with capacitive filter):


Wow, thank you for doing an incredible job of providing the "thorough and complete" approach to my circuit! My original thought was that there must be some kind of simpler or shortcut type method if only the peak capacitor voltage is of interest, but either way, I greatly appreciate seeing how the fully detailed analysis is done. And yes, I'd definitely also be interested in seeing the analysis for the double half-wave circuit, if you don't mind posting it!

In the photo below, there is a partial study of the double half-wave signal and, in the next photo, there are written: the subprograms for the Fourier analysis of any signal (including the SPTC function):


